# Joomla reset sql field selection with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, joomla

How can I reset a Joomla sql type field to it's initial value?

The set up:

I hava a dropdown with three 'type' options 'item number' 'standard shape' and 'non standard shape' which triggers a javascript function to show the selected div and hide the others on a joomla form. The `switch` function also resets the fields in the hidden div to their initial state. The 'standard shape' div contains another dropdown with a list of shapes generated from a joomla sql type field which triggers more javascript to display an image of the shape.

The scenario:

If I set the 'type' to 'Standard shape' and select a shape e.g. 'Rectangle' and then change the switch to 'non standard shape' and then back again, the shape drop down retains it's value of 'Rectangle' even though it's value is null. The problem is if I try to reselect 'rectangle' the `onchange` event to show the image does not trigger.

Hope I explained that well enough but I can try to clarify further if it's not clear.

Here is the code:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JHtml::addIncludePath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/helpers/html');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');
JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');

// Import CSS
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet('components/com_escorders/assets/css/escorders.css');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    js = jQuery.noConflict();

    js(document).ready(function(){
        setitemtype(true);
        setshapelabels();
    });

    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
        if(task == 'product.cancel'){
            Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('product-form'));
        }
        else{

            if (task != 'product.cancel' && document.formvalidator.isValid(document.id('product-form'))) {
                Joomla.submitform(task, document.getElementById('product-form'));
            }
            else {
                alert('<?php echo $this->escape(JText::_('JGLOBAL_VALIDATION_FORM_FAILED')); ?>');
            }
        }
    }

    function setitemtype(init)
    {
        var selection = jQuery('#jform_type').find(":selected").text();
        var id = jQuery('#jform_itemid').val();

        if (init !== true)
        {
            jQuery('#jform_itemid').val('');
        };

        if (selection === 'Item Number') 
        {
            resetshape();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_itemid').attr('readonly',false);
            jQuery('#jform_shape').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_shape').val('');
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').val('');
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').val('');
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').val('');
            jQuery('#jform_drawingfile').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_drawingurl').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_drawingurl').val('');
        } 
        else if (selection === 'Standard Shape')
        {
            var shape = jQuery('#jform_shape').val();
            if (shape) 
            {
                jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();              
            }
            jQuery('#jform_itemid').attr('readonly',true);
            jQuery('#jform_shape').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_drawingfile').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_drawingurl').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_drawingurl').val('');
            setshapelabels();
        }
        else
        {
            resetshape();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_itemid').attr('readonly',true);
            jQuery('#jform_shape').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_shape').val('');
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').val('');
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').val('');
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').val('');
            jQuery('#jform_drawingfile').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_drawingurl').closest('.control-group').show();
        };
    }

    function setshapelabels()
    {
        var selection = jQuery('#jform_shape').find(":selected").text();

        switch(selection)
        {
        case 'Rectangle':
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            jQuery('#shape-img').attr('src', '../images/escorders/shapes/rectangle.gif')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').text('Length')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Length</strong><br />Length Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').text('Height')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Height</strong><br />Height Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').text('Dimension 3')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Dimension 3</strong><br />Dimension 3 - Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            break;
        case 'Rhomboid':
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            jQuery('#shape-img').attr('src', '../images/escorders/shapes/rhomboid.gif')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').text('Length')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Length</strong><br />Length Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').text('Height')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Height</strong><br />Height Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').text('Angle')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Angle</strong><br />Angle Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            break;
        case 'Round':
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            jQuery('#shape-img').attr('src', '../images/escorders/shapes/round.gif')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').text('Diameter')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Diameter</strong><br />Diameter Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').text('Dimension 2')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Dimension 2</strong><br />Dimension 2 - Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').text('Dimension 3')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Dimension 3</strong><br />Dimension 3 - Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            break;
        case 'Sector':
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            jQuery('#shape-img').attr('src', '../images/escorders/shapes/sector.gif')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').text('Diameter')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Diameter</strong><br />Diameter Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').text('Angle')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Angle</strong><br />Angle Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').text('Dimension 3')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Dimension 3</strong><br />Dimension 3 - Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            break;
        case 'Trapezium':
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            jQuery('#shape-img').attr('src', '../images/escorders/shapes/trapezium.gif')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').text('Length')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Length</strong><br />Length Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').text('Height')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Height</strong><br />Height Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').text('Angle')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Angle</strong><br />Angle Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            break;
        case 'Triangle':
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            jQuery('#shape-img').attr('src', '../images/escorders/shapes/triangle.gif')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').text('Length')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Length</strong><br />Length Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').text('Angle')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Angle</strong><br />Angle Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').text('Dimension 3')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Dimension 3</strong><br />Dimension 3 - Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').show();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').show();
            break;
        default:
            jQuery('#shape-img').attr('src', '')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').text('Dimension 1')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Dimension 1</strong><br />Dimension 1 - Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').text('Dimension 2')
            jQuery('#jform_dim2-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Dimension 2</strong><br />Dimension 2 - Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').text('Dimension 3')
            jQuery('#jform_dim3-lbl').attr('data-original-title', '<strong>Dimension 3</strong><br />Dimension 3 - Value')
            jQuery('#jform_dim1').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim2').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#jform_dim3').closest('.control-group').hide();
            jQuery('#shape-img-container').hide();
        };
        buildshapestring();
    }

    function changedecimalplaces(el)
    {
        var num = parseFloat(el.value).toFixed(3);
        el.value = num 
        buildshapestring();
    }

    function buildshapestring() 
    {
        var selection = jQuery('#jform_type').find(":selected").text();

        if (selection === 'Standard Shape')
        {
            var shape = jQuery('#jform_shape').val();
            var shapestring = '';
            var dim1 = jQuery('#jform_dim1').val();
            var dim2 = jQuery('#jform_dim2').val();
            var dim3 = jQuery('#jform_dim3').val();

            switch(shape)
            {
            case 'Rectangle':
                shapestring  = 'Rect [L:'+dim1+'] [H:'+dim2+']';
                break;
            case 'Rhomboid':
                shapestring  = 'Rhom [L:'+dim1+'] [H:'+dim2+'] [A:'+dim3+']';
                break;
            case 'Round':
                shapestring  = 'Roun [D:'+dim1+']';
                break;
            case 'Sector':
                shapestring  = 'Sect [D:'+dim1+'] [A:'+dim2+']';
                break;
            case 'Trapezium':
                shapestring  = 'Rhom [L:'+dim1+'] [H:'+dim2+'] [A:'+dim3+']';
                break;
            case 'Triangle':
                shapestring  = 'Tria [L:'+dim1+'] [A:'+dim2+']';
                break;
            default:
                shapestring  = '';
            };

            jQuery('#jform_itemid').val(shapestring);
        }
    }

    function resetshape()
    {
        jQuery('jform_shape').val('');
    }

    function clearselectedfile () 
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var control = js("#jform_drawingfile");
        control.replaceWith( control = control.clone( true ) );
        jQuery('#jform_itemid').val('');
        jQuery('#jform_drawingurl').val('');
    }

    function fillfilename ()
    {
        var filename = jQuery('#jform_drawingfile').val().replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
        jQuery('#jform_itemid').val(filename);
        jQuery('#jform_drawingurl').val('#');
    }

</script>

<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_escorders&layout=edit&id=' . (int) $this->item->id); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="adminForm" id="product-form" class="form-validate">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span10 form-horizontal">
            <fieldset class="adminform">

            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('id'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('id'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('type'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('type'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('itemid'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('itemid'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('shape'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('shape'); ?></div>
                <div id="shape-img-container">
                    <img id="shape-img" src="">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('dim1'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('dim1'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('dim2'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('dim2'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('dim3'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('dim3'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('drawingfile'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('drawingfile'); ?><button id="clearfile" onclick="clearselectedfile()">Clear</button></div>  
            </div>          
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('drawingurl'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('drawingurl'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('state'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('state'); ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('created_by'); ?></div>
                <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('created_by'); ?></div>
            </div>


            </fieldset>
        </div>      

        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>

    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Try putting all your javascript inside `$document->addScriptDeclaration(' .... ');`

Comment: @Lodder Thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but no joy unfortunately! Is it good practice to that anyway?

Comment: well yes because `addScriptDeclaration()` is a Joomla feature that allows you to add custom Javascript and it will get pushed to the `<head>` of the template

Comment: @Lodder Thanks, I'll start using that from now on!

Comment: Be sure you're also importing the jquery library. After using what I recommended in my comment above, are you getting any errros in the browser console?

Comment: @Lodder No errors, it functions exactly the same both ways, everything works as expected except in that one scenario that I outlined in the question

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in that the functions run only once and not after each change in the select box. Try modifying the code like this:

```
js(document).ready(function(){
    setitemtype(true);
    setshapelabels();

    js('#jform_type').change(function(){
        setitemtype(true);
        setshapelabels();
    });

    js('#jform_itemid').change(function(){
        setitemtype(true);
        setshapelabels();
    });
});
```

Docs on change() [here](http://api.jquery.com/change/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work, the change event is firing but the drop down is not being reset to null to all other selections will work except for the one that was previously selected.